# Como podemos lidar com a falta de empatia dos novos usuários?

Tags: debate, comportamento

## O ambiente tem que ser apático?

Uma coisa que eu tenho percebido nesses últimos meses é como muitos usuários novos não demostram muita empatia com quem deseja ajudar, acabam agindo de forma grosseira e muitas vezes desrespeitando o colega da comunidade.

Separei este caso que ocorreu agora pouco para ilustrar. Veja um comentário que não parece ser amigável (em meu ponto de vista):

> Ok, vou me retirar . Parece que não fui muito aceito aqui , só queria
>   uma ajuda.

E toda a conversa:

> gato - Olá Vanderlei. Qual seria a relação da pergunta com as tags
>   java, html, css, sql e python?
>
> AP - Desculpa é que sou novo aqui ainda não sei criar Tags.
>
> AP - Vc pode me ajudar nessa pergunta , por favor?
>
> gato - Sua pergunta me parece ser puramente sobre estatística, se sim
>   ela esta fora de escopo, se houver relação com programação nela
>   poderia estar no escopo do site. Poderia editar ela e ser mais
>   especifico em relação ao seu problema e também fornecer um contexto?
>   Aprenda mais sobre o site aqui no tour.
>
> AP - Ok, vou me retirar . Parece que não fui muito aceito aqui , só
>   queria uma ajuda.

O [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363039/27190) referente a conversa foi removido pelo próprio OP. Basicamente, a questão parecia ser fora de escopo, no entanto, mesmo assim eu estava disposto e ajuda-lo fornecendo uns links e uma [comunidade](https://stats.stackexchange.com) que trata do assunto da pergunta, que aparenta ser sobre estatística. No entanto, a postura do usuário que fez com que ele removesse a pergunta me impossibilitou de continuar ajudando. *E quem sai perdendo nisso?*

Esses casos estão ficando mais comuns, a cada dia que passa, claro que eu possa estar errado, porém, é melhor remediar. E sem falar que esta falta de empatia por parte dos usuários novatos (claro que não são todos) gera um desanimo em continuar ajudando e moderando o site.

Para mim, acho que a **empatia tem que estar presente em todo mundo**, tanto em novos usuários como em veteranos, e eu sei também que há veteranos que aparentam não ser muito empáticos, mas isso é outra questão, o foco é nos novatos.

## Qual abordagem devemos seguir?

Aqui eu quero me focar em quais soluções devem ser implementadas para evitar que isso piore, e reverter o quadro apenas fazendo os questionamentos.

Eu mesmo não sei se agi da forma correta, talvez eu tenha ofendido o AR com meus questionamentos sobre a pergunta dele. A maneira que eu agi foi correta? Fui apático?

Eu sempre tento me colocar no lugar das pessoas aqui, por mais que as vezes é difícil fazer. Não sei se vocês fazem isto, mas eu vejo como um possível caminho.

Tendo isso em vista, fica as questões:

- Como podemos lidar com a falta de empatia dos novos usuários?
- Ou, como podemos desenvolver mais a empatia entre os usuários aqui na comunidade?

Comment: Pra mim não tem nada a ser feito se o usuário só quer sugar do site sem nem entender como ele funciona. Empatia é pra quem faz por merecer, uma pessoa q chega num lugar se comportando contra as regras dali, e quando educadamente orientada, ao invés de adequar-se, se faz de vitima, não é bem vinda, e o melhor que faz é se retirar mesmo.

Comment: Tem uma máquina do tempo? Acho que é única forma :) E o cara ainda teve a pergunta positivada, imagine se fosse negativada o que ele ia dizer sobre não ser aceito. Não tem o que fazer ,algumas pessoas tem sérios problemas, ou são até mesmo desonestos e pegam carona nessa onda de que todo mundo é um bebê frágil que precisa pegar no colo e fazer tudo pra ele do jeito que ele quer, se você o balançá-lo de um jeito diferente já ferrou.

Comment: É, uma máquina do tempo e um "retrocesso" de postura talvez ajudasse, pq o que aconteceu foi uma série de coisas desse tipo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmhTG.jpg (e olhe que já tem 10 anos o quadrinho pelo visto) - Não vou dizer que é o caso desse post específico, mas tem um "floquismo de neve" imperando em tudo quanto é canto recentemente (que comigo não cola, por sinal - tou aqui pra ajudar todo mundo do mesmo jeito só que se desequilibrar pra um lado eu tendo um pouco pro outro pra compensar).

Comment: Não acho que é falta de empatia, é preguiça de entender como o site funciona. A maioria está acostumada com redes sociais que não tem regras e pode falar o que quiser, de qq jeito, sem consequência e sem sair da bolha/zona de conforto. Qdo chegam num site mais "rígido" que a média, em que é preciso um mínimo de esforço para participar adequadamente, se assustam e vem com esse papo de "não sou aceito" (vide os que se ofendem com negativos em perguntas totalmente fora do escopo). Não acho que vc agiu errado, pelo contrário, achei sua postura bem adequada

Comment: Não é falta de empatia deles, parece mais falta de outras coisas. É compreensível que novos usuários se sintam acuados, e às vezes o mecanismo do site e certos comportamentos de alguns podem acentuar isso. Todo mundo está sujeito a se sentir assim ao chegar num ambiente novo. Parece que as pessoas estão esquecendo que isso é normal. Ficam frustradas e não sabem lidar, e aí a reação é espernear, ou se retirar, rejeitando e negando tudo que é diferente daquilo que elas esperavam ou gostariam. Para reverter isso, é preciso ter um mínimo de consciência de si, que muitos não têm.

Comment: Só para dar uma opinião meio solta, eu acho que você foi bem eloquente e simpático. Não dava para fazer muito mais. Agora não podemos esquecer que isto é texto escrito na net e por vezes as pessoas inferem tonalidade errada no que está escrito, como acontece recorrentemente com o sarcasmo. Talvez tenha sido por ai.

Comment: Não se sinta mal, suas palavras não demostraram hostilidade, as vezes alguns usuários preferem se fazer de vítima como já comentaram. E o pior é que fazem isso muitas vezes por falta de humildade ou por preguiça de procurar atender os critérios mínimos para manter uma boa qualidade do "material" do site. Usuários desse tipo nada mais são do que mal exemplo, e concordo que devemos prezar pelo bom nível das perguntas e resposta. Mesmo que vez ou outra tendo que tomar esse tipo de atitude e fazer uma crítica construtiva que é mal interpretada. Mas se o cara não sabe escrever como vai interpretar

Comment: Algumas coisas eu acho incríveis: tem gente que quer ser programador mais não sabe colocar uma tag numa pergunta (entre outras coisas, como saber escrever, por exemplo).

Answer (score 19):

Na minha opinião isso é um exemplo claro do "atual cenário geral", o famoso "mimimi", "vitimismo", o que ocorre na maioria das vezes.

Se a pessoa quer aprender, até "tomando porrada" aprende (não que pancadas sejam necessárias, mas um dia aprendemos a levantar e seguir em frente. Essa é a vida).

Eu "entrei" no SOpt a pouco mais de 1 ano, e hoje mudou MUITO essa questão de "como tratar novos usuários". Parece que querem que você estenda tapete vermelho, e nem ao menos leem o mínimo de instruções de como fazer uma pergunta (quando não acham ruim que você mande o link para tal).

Acho que há certo limite em "carregar no colo" com "ser receptivo", principalmente quando se está claro que o AP fez mal feita por preguiça (ao meu ver seu exemplo é claro). É muito raro ver falta de cordialismo, pelo contrário, acho que estão até perdendo o filtro de perguntas que poderiam ser fechadas porque ficam esperando o novo usuário "consertá-la", quando no meio tempo não aparecem respostas com "achismo", piorando ainda mais.

Quanto ao seu caso, você foi apenas simples e claro, o que para esse portal ao meu ver seria o ideal. Focar em mostrar como funciona, e não que é um "suporte".

Finalizando, acho que está bom como está, mesmo que ainda considero um pouco de cordialidade demais, o que "acostuma mal" alguns, e como reflexo disso, só vem piorando.

Answer (score 14):

Acredito que você precisa ser o mais neutro possível, apenas indicar que existe o problema no formato, na formatação e afins, sem precisar explicar nem mesmo como fazer a correção e nem responder a replica. A questão não é nem de ser educado, mas motivar o usuário a sair da sua zona de conforto e pesquisar uns minutos a mais de como fazer uma pergunta ou ate mesmo responder.

E se a pergunta ou resposta continua ainda com um nível baixo, sinalize como "qualidade muito baixa" o outro.

Answer (score 3):

Eu gostaria de compartilhar a minha visão.
 Recém estou aprendendo a programar, e eu não tenho conhecimento para criar posts complexos explicando detalhadamente os problemas que os meus algoritmos possuem.
Então a minha pergunta leva flag, voto negativo, etc. Não irei julgar, vocês tem suas regras. Mas pessoas que não possuem conhecimento ou simplesmente não estão com tempo ou não possuem capacidade para elaborar mais complexidade sofrem muito com tudo isso.

O problema de tentar manter um padrão alto demais é que muitos vão só voltar pro site pra visitar uma pergunta, pegar a resposta que quer e ir embora.

Comment: Concordo com vc em parte. A parte que concordo é que acho que a comunidade de uma forma geral podia tentar ajudar os novos usuários de uma forma mais amistosa, principalmente justificando o voto negativo para quem é novo usuário e não entende direito como construir uma resposta. Só dar negativo em um novo usuário não ajuda muito para que ele entenda como proceder. O que não concordo é em baixar o nível da resposta só pq não tem tempo para responder, ou pq não lembra onde está a fonte etc... isso não é justificativa para uma resposta fraca e sem fundamento. []´s

Comment: Concordo muito com a sua opinião.

Comment: Tem o outro lado tb: se vc não consegue explicar o problema, fica mais difícil alguém conseguir ajudar. Se está sem tempo, deixe para postar quando tiver tempo (é melhor do que escrever algo mal feito, como já disse o @hugocsl acima). E ultimamente a grande maioria das perguntas é ruim, fora do escopo, mal escrita, alguns até comentam e tentam ajudar, mas chega uma hora que as pessoas cansam e simplesmente votam negativo. Se todos lessem o [tour], a [help], a página [ask] e como montar um [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), diminuiria este "cansaço" e todos sairiam ganhando.

Comment: E já vi uma palestra de uma funcionária do Stack Overflow dizendo que a grande maioria dos usuários acessa o site deslogado (ou seja, muitos sequer têm conta no site), copia/cola e tchau, então isso não é necessariamente um problema em si. Afinal, manter um padrão alto é o que tornou esse site o que é, e muita coisa eu aprendi nas respostas complexas e detalhadas, que eu jamais teria capacidade de escrever (mas **que bom** que alguém tem, e **melhor ainda** que o site atrai tais especialistas). A mer ver, esse é o grande diferencial do site, que seria perdido se abaixássemos o padrão.

Comment: Mesmo que seja iniciante, precisa se comunicar direito, isso é requisito para qualquer coisa na vida. Tem perguntas de iniciantes com ótima votação, pois estão bem elaboradas. Da mesma forma se um bom programador fizer uma pergunta mal elaborada, os votos da comunidade em geral não vão ser favoráveis. Ser iniciante não tem nada a ver com jogar coisas de qualquer jeito no site e esperar que o outros se virem (vale para todos, não tou aplicando ao seu caso especificamente). E é importante entender que aqui não é um site de ajuda e sim um repositório de conhecimento e para isso precisa de padrão.

Answer (score 2):

Minha opinião é compartilhada da mesma do RBz e apenas complementando. Hoje está sendo formada uma sociedade "**emocionalmente fraca**" onde qualquer coisa que ela não queira ver ou escutar faça com que gere um "mimimi".

"Quem quer aprender, aprende, mesmo que pra isso leve umas pancadas."

Você não vai à um lugar e sai fazendo o que quiser do jeito que quiser sem ver as regras daquele local. Por exemplo, você não vai abrir uma cerveja dentro de uma igreja, porque sabe que isso não é certo, e logo se fizer ninguém vai "estender o tapete vermelho" e te convidar até o altar.

Então acho que é um pouco de ignorância de novos usuários também.